# Why did TC39 name JavaScript's array predicate functions `some` and `every` instead of `any` and `all`?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, naming, history

Python, Ruby, Rust, Haskell, Kotlin, C#, C++, Perl, MATLAB, SQL, and R all call their respective array predicate checking functions `any` and `all`.

Is there any record of why JavaScript's designers decided to deviate from the naming convention other languages have used for these functions since the 90's?

Some Lisp-family languages (specifically Common Lisp and Clojure) seem to be the only other notable users of `some` and `every`.

Comment: Even C++ does it, [sort](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) [of](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/all_any_none_of) (they append `_of`).

Comment: "JavaScript's designers"

Comment: [Common Lisp uses `some` and `every` as well](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_everyc.htm#some). How hard did you look?

Comment: @PhilipKendall good catch, thanks! I've edited the question to refer to Lisp variants more generally. If you know of any others I'd be very interested to hear.

Answer (score 1):

The higher-order array methods `map`, `filter`, `some`, `every` were added to JavaScript by Mozilla in 2005. This was before Go, Rust, and Kotlin even existed (AFAIK) and before C# and Python had any/all. They became part of the ECMAScript standard with ECMAScript 5 in 2009.

The methods were almost certainly inspired by Lisp, which had similar functions for list processing. Lisp and Scheme were a strong influence on JavaScript. Scheme, a Lisp dialect, is specifically mentioned as an inspiration in the ECMAScript 5 specification (along with Java and Self).

Worth noting SQL supports both `ANY` and `SOME` as alias.

Answer (score 0):

I cant find the notes for `any` and `all` but you can see this proposal for `includes`

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-Array.prototype.includes

which mentions:

> Why includes instead of has? If you survey existing APIs, has is used
> for conceptual "keys," whereas includes is used for conceptual
> "values."

And the notes on the discussion:

> Array.prototype.includes
>
> DD: CC + FF in betas
>
> DD: Test262 works
>
> DD: Safari doesn't have TypeArray.prototype.includes
>
> DD: Stage 4?
>
> DD: should it be in unscopables?
>
> BT: if it not in unscopeables it may be ok?
>
> BT: real world with no breaks, should be good.
>
> DD: lets make it unscopable
>
> DD: stage 4?
>
> YK: yup
>
> Conclusion/Resolution Move to stage 4 (tomorrow when it's added to
> @@unscopables)

Presumably the same kind of thought went into `any` and `all` what does the underlying engine support? what do we have already? etc

Comment: oh man, [this linked discussion](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/having-a-non-enumerable-array-prototype-contains-may-not-be-web-compatible) is depressing. Thanks for the link!